# jtds TDS Protocol error: Invalid packet type

Tags: varchar, jtds, sybase-asa

I'm connecting to Sybase ASA v11.0.1 using the jTDS library (v1.2.6) and I'm getting the following error every time I try to return varchar data

> Protocol error: Invalid packet type `0x0`

(or `x4` or `x7`)

The queries work fine when I return a timestamp or numeric value.  Any idea what is causing this error or how to resolve it?

Comment: FYI you can ask questions related to Sybase SQL Anywhere (i.e. ASA) at http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems Sybase is not supported by 1.2.6 according to this https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104389/thread/d6e2efe3/

But I see this sometimes when the timeout closes the connection while I read the result set